# JetPack Compose - Best practices for method length

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, detekt

I am trying to integrate detekt with JetPack Compose project and as a rule

```
 LongMethod:
    active: true
    threshold: 60
```

and as compose recommend passing each parameter in separate line the method length exceeds the 100 lines of code, So I am wondering what is the best threshold to use for composable functions or if there is a way to exclude composables from this rule?

there are some detekt customization for compose [here](https://detekt.dev/compose.html) but nothing about this rule

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to encapsulate your params in a data class. This is something similar what's is done is some Material Compose components like: `Scaffold` (which uses `ScaffoldState`, or `LazyColumn`/`LazyListState`, etc.

This recommendation is described [here](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/docs/compose-api-guidelines.md#hoisted-state-types).

Instead of using:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun VerticalScroller(
    scrollPosition: Int,
    scrollRange: Int,
    onScrollPositionChange: (Int) -> Unit,
    onScrollRangeChange: (Int) -> Unit
) {
```

you should use:

```kotlin
@Stable
interface VerticalScrollerState {
    var scrollPosition: Int
    var scrollRange: Int
}

@Composable
fun VerticalScroller(
    verticalScrollerState: VerticalScrollerState
) {
```